# Javascript, click, doubleclick and drag in the same element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, event-handling

I'm in need of a function that figures out if the user is clicking, double-clicking or dragging the mouse.

Since it's all happening in the same canvas using the normal events doesn't work. I found this through google:

> It is inadvisable to bind handlers to both the click and dblclick
>   events for the same element. The sequence of events triggered varies
>   from browser to browser, with some receiving two click events and
>   others only one. If an interface that reacts differently to single-
>   and double-clicks cannot be avoided, then the dblclick event should be
>   simulated within the click handler. We can achieve this by saving a
>   timestamp in the handler, and then comparing the current time to the
>   saved timestamp on subsequent clicks. If the difference is small
>   enough, we can treat the click as a double-click.

How could I achieve this in a good way?

First see if the click is pressed (for drag)? When it is released treat it as a click? and then if clicked again doubleclick?

How can I translate this to code? Help appreciated.

Comment: This is where I would like to use it, the click is at the bottom of the script (only single click atm). http://jsfiddle.net/hustlerinc/EkWyZ/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following should get you started, I'm using jQuery just to make it easier to show, this can be implemented with straight JS, it's just a lot of noise

```
$(function() {

  var doubleClickThreshold = 50;  //ms
  var lastClick = 0;
  var isDragging = false;
  var isDoubleClick = false;

  $node = ("#mycanvas");
  $node.click(function(){
    var thisClick = new Date().getTime();
    var isDoubleClick = thisClick - lastClick < doubleClickThreshold;
    lastClick = thisClick;
  });

  $node.mousedown(function() {
    mouseIsDown = true;
  });

  $node.mouseUp(function() {
    isDragging = false;
    mouseIsDown = false;
  });

  // Using document so you can drag outside of the canvas, use $node
  // if you cannot drag outside of the canvas
  $(document).mousemove(function() {
     if (mouseIsDown) {
       isDragging = true;
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes it is jQuery, but that is only so I don't have to pollute the post with extra code that makes it work cross-browser. It's not meant for you to cut and paste, just for you to see the logic

Comment: yeah I understand that I have to edit it, just wanted to make sure I read the code right. I'll try to translate it =)

Comment: Thanks, implemented my own dblclick event with your example

Answer (score 0):

I would probably work around this by putting a timer in the click event to check for another click.

```
time = 0
if(new Date().getTime() < time + 400) {
  // Double click
  throw new Error("Stop execution");
}
if(!!time)
  throw new Error("Stop execution");
time = new Date().getTime();
// Single click
```

Something like that. Untested, and I can't think right now for some odd reason.